# Как добавить новую колонку в таблице и установить для неё значение?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу отредактировать таблицу в базе данных, добавив дополнительную колонку и присвоить всем записям в таблице определённое значение. Сделал следующим образом:

```
ALTER TABLE snapshots ADD COLUMN affiliation varchar(1);
INSERT INTO snapshots (affiliation) VALUES 'f';
```

На что сервером был дан ответ `INSERT 0 1` и, как я понял, поле affiliation заполнилось только в нулевой записи. А как присвоить полю affiliation какое-то значение во всех записях в таблицы?

Comment: Изменение значений поля существующих записей выполняется запросом UPDATE.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, сработало.

Comment: если в новом столбце не может быть NULL's, то можно одной командой: `ALTER TABLE snapshots ADD COLUMN affiliation varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f';`